# Uploaded a installation file to facebook application

Tags: c#, facebook, upload

I developed a desktop application using facebook account.

I want to know how can I upload a installation file to my facebook application's page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, until you run it behind webserver. I don't think it would be good for facebook users to execute unknown applications

Comment: This application, is my final project of my studies. I programmed it as a desktop application due to a lack of knowledge /no much free time to study web development. My advisor want us, at first step, to upload the installation to be available for the rest of the students/ lecturers to use the application and to get a review. So the people who going to play it know us and trust us, so this is not the problem.